# Display an image as response to jQuery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery

Im working on converting and editing images with php "wideimage" class.

I have a php file which is called with ajax from html and then it outputs a image which i have to display in html.

The php file outputs an image everytime which i have to catch it and display in html.
When user uploads the image..It dosent get stored anywhere the wideimage class takes  care of it and outputs an image.

Comment: What's the question exactly ?

Comment: Hi raveline its ..how to display an image as response to jquey ajax request.Thanks

Comment: That doesn't quite explain it better. That's just the headline again. So, are you saying your AJAX request returns an Content-Type:image/* response by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified example from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), assuming php returning image path (data).

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'wideimage.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html('<img src="' + data + '" />');
  }
});
```

Comment: It does not return the image src. it returns the image itself. How exactly I don't know.